# SQL Query to parse XML and remove data and send remaining results to multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, xml-parsing

Is there a way to parse XML string data from a column from a table and easily be able to remove parts of the XML string with a wildcard automatically?

Example:

```html
Example: 

<audit><fieldid>id="John"<fieldid>id="bob</audit>  
  
  How would i be able to remove just <fieldid>id="bob?
```

```html
How would i be able to remove just <fieldid>id="bob?  

If there are more values after <fieldid>id="bob, how would i be able remove those as well, but keep the </audit> in place at the end.

I have tried the following Update Statement and it did not work with a wildcard:

Update Table
Set column=Replace(Column, '<fieldid>id="bob%', </Audit>
```

I have tried the following but wildcards in a replace function do not work:

update table
set column=replace(column,'id="bob%',

Comment: can you give an example of what you are trying to do and what you have doen already! Thanks

Comment: not sure why you were downvoted! any how what is your SQL engine? is it SQL Server or Oracle etc..

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumption:

the pattern id="bob will only occur once.

This should do it. You just need to replace the variable @var with your column:

```
DECLARE @Var VARCHAR(MAX) = '<audit><fieldid>id="John"<fieldid>id="bob</audit>';

SELECT REPLACE(@Var, SUBSTRING(@Var, PATINDEX('%<fieldid>id="bob%', @Var), PATINDEX('%<%', SUBSTRING(@Var, PATINDEX('%<fieldid>id="bob%', @Var)+1, LEN(@Var)))), '');
```

RESULT:

[image]

To Answer your comment **"Is it possible to have the script remove all values after bob and be replaced with ?"**

```
DECLARE @Var VARCHAR(MAX) = '<audit><fieldid>id="John"<fieldid>id="bob<fieldid>id="John"</audit>';

SELECT REPLACE(@Var, SUBSTRING(@Var, PATINDEX('%<fieldid>id="bob%', @Var), PATINDEX('%</audit>%', SUBSTRING(@Var, PATINDEX('%<fieldid>id="bob%', @Var)+1, LEN(@Var)))), '');
```

RESULT:

[image]

Comment: How would I be able to implement your script into a loop?

Comment: why would you want to use loops in an SQL query. you should have a a set based approach. Having said that there are some cases where loops are needed but they are very rare.

Comment: Is it possible to have the script remove all values after bob and be replaced with </audit>?

Comment: sure is its actually easier to do that then what its doing now

Comment: regarding the loop, what I basically want to do is create a loop that will run this script against a table and then copy the result of each row without the this value <fieldid>id="bob%' and the values after to another table.  Each row will be different.